# ZMQ - Packet Loss

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am planning to implement the Pub / Sub model using ZMQ and thought of trying ZMQ sample (weather) program. [Note: I've modified the program a bit]

**Following are the observations regarding ZMQ:**

- Post setting up servers and running program couple of times,found
  that there is HUGE packet loss
- I'm pretty sure that underlying hardware is good enough from Processor, Memory, and Network bandwidth point-of-view.
- Even tried with TCP tunning
  recommends (few of them)

  So now I would like to understand if I am
  missing any optimization settings or any other recommendations that
  should be implemented as per ZeroMQ performance expectations.

**Please find the link of Pastebin**

---

## [Publisher Sample Code:](https://pastebin.com/VVQX9jD2)

```
//
//  Weather update server in C++
//  Binds PUB socket to tcp://*:5556
//  Publishes random weather updates
//
//  Olivier Chamoux <olivier.chamoux@fr.thalesgroup.com>
//
#include <cppzmq-master/zmq.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std::chrono;

#if (defined (WIN32))
#include <zhelpers.hpp>
#endif

#define within(num) (unsigned long) ((float) num * random () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //  Prepare our context and publisher
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");
    unsigned long ticks_count = atoi(argv [1]);
    //publisher.bind("ipc://weather.ipc");                // Not usable on Windows.

    //  Initialize random number generator
    srandom ((unsigned) time (NULL));
    unsigned long counter = 0;
    zmq_sleep(5);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
    auto timestamp3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration).count();

    for(unsigned long i = 1; i <= ticks_count; i++) {

        unsigned long zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;

        //  Get values that will fool the boss
        zipcode     = ++counter;
        temperature = within (215) - 80;
        relhumidity = within (50) + 10;

        //  Send message to all subscribers
        zmq::message_t message(20);
        snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 20 ,
            "%lu %lu %lu", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
        publisher.send(message);
        // usleep(0);
        std::cout << "i, zipcode: "<< i << ", " << zipcode << std::endl;

        // Code to print missing packets
        if(i != zipcode)
            std::cout << "Missing Packet - Expected: "<< i << ", Sent: " << zipcode << std::endl;

    }
    now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    duration = now.time_since_epoch();
    auto timestamp4 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration).count();
    unsigned long diff = timestamp4 - timestamp3;
    std::cout << "Time Taken (nanoseconds): " << diff << std::endl;

    zmq_sleep(300);
    return 0;
}
```

**Commands:**

Build =>

```
g++ pub.cpp -o pub -lstdc++ -lzmq
```

Execute =>

```
./pub 22686
```

---

## [Subscriber Sample Code:](https://pastebin.com/s0gJYcti)

```
//
//  Weather update client in C++
//  Connects SUB socket to tcp://localhost:5556
//  Collects weather updates and finds avg temp in zipcode
//
//  Olivier Chamoux <olivier.chamoux@fr.thalesgroup.com>
//
#include <cppzmq-master/zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context (1);

    //  Socket to talk to server
    std::cout << "Collecting updates from weather server…\n" << std::endl;
    zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");

    //  Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
    const char *filter = "";//(argc > 1)? argv [1]: "10001 ";
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen (filter));
    unsigned long ticks_count = atoi(argv [1]);
    std::cout << "Ticks Count: " << ticks_count << std::endl;
    //  Process 100 updates
    unsigned long update_nbr;
    unsigned long total_temp = 0;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
    auto timestamp3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration).count();

    for (update_nbr = 1; update_nbr <= ticks_count; update_nbr++) {

        zmq::message_t update;
        unsigned long zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;

        subscriber.recv(&update);

        std::istringstream iss(static_cast<char*>(update.data()));
        iss >> zipcode >> temperature >> relhumidity ;

        total_temp += temperature;
        std::cout << "update_nbr, zipcode: "<< update_nbr << ", " << zipcode << std::endl;

        // Code to print missing packets
        if(update_nbr != zipcode)
            std::cout << "Missing Packet - Expected: "<< update_nbr << ", Received: " << zipcode << std::endl;
    }

    now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    duration = now.time_since_epoch();
    auto timestamp4 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration).count();
    unsigned long diff = timestamp4 - timestamp3;
    std::cout << "Time Taken (nanoseconds): " << diff << std::endl;
    std::cout     << "Program Complete" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Commands:**

Build =>

```
g++ sub.cpp -o sub -lstdc++ -lzmq
```

Execute =>

```
./sub 22686
```

Comment: You cannot miss data on TCP - thats the whole point of TCP - either it is sent or you end up with some form of an error (but error can get suppressed on another level).

Comment: @darune
Thanks for your input, I completely agree that TCP is used for reliable communication and thus it ensures that you'll get all packets at destination based on SEQ & ACK flags. (We have a sample TCP Server / Client program and there's NO PACKET LOSS, when we use raw protocols)
As you might have noticed, we are using ZEROMQ and it has its own layer (abstraction) over Raw TCP / IP so I think we are facing packet loss issue.
Also, note we are using Pub/Sub pattern using ZEROMQ so that could enable possibility of different working style for above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Welcome to the [Zen-of-Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) : observed results are fully documented

**Reason:**

> When a **`ZMQ_PUB`** socket enters the mute state due to having reached the high water mark for a subscriber, then ***any messages*** that would be sent to the subscriber in question shall instead ***be dropped*** until the mute state ends. The **`zmq_send()`** function shall never block for this socket type.

**Solution:**

**Either** include a proper sizing of resources,
**or** design a bi-directional handshaking, that will adaptively throttle the cadence of (otherwise blind) calls of the `publisher.send(message)`-method, depending on the ability to handle the flow of processing smoothly and in sync.

---

### **`PUB`**-side: add

```
int           hwm_nMSGs = 0;                    //  A value of zero means no limit
unsigned long buf_SizeB = 100 * ticks_count;
publisher.setsockopt( ZMQ_SNDBUF, buf_SizeB, sizeof ( buf_SizeB ) );
publisher.setsockopt( ZMQ_SNDHWM, hwm_nMSGs, sizeof ( hwm_nMSGs ) );
// _________________________________________________________ CONFIG b4 .bind()
publisher.bind( "tcp://*:5556" );
...
// ___________________________________________________________________ .unbind()
zmq_unbind( publisher, "tcp://*:5556" );                            // .unbind()
zmq_ctx_term( context );                                            // .term()
```

---

### **`SUB`**-side: add

```
unsigned long hwm_nMSGs =   3 * ticks_count;
unsigned long buf_SizeB = 100 * ticks_count;
subscriber.setsockopt( ZMQ_RCVHWM, hwm_nMSGs, sizeof ( hwm_nMSGs ) );
subscriber.setsockopt( ZMQ_RCVBUF, buf_SizeB, sizeof ( buf_SizeB ) );
// _________________________________________________________ CONFIG b4 .connect()
subscriber.connect( "tcp://localhost:5556" );
...
// ___________________________________________________________________ .close()
subscriber.close();                                                 // .close()
zmq_ctx_term( context );                                            // .term()
```

**Last but not least**,
never assume a natural order of network packets' arrivals, the many-paths routed-networks may deliver and do deliver out-of-order, so the last condition: `if(update_nbr != zipcode)` will flag all out-of-order deliveries even when no messages were dropped on either `{ PUB | SUB }`-side due to missing resources or lost during a transport.

Given there was no indication about which ZeroMQ version / language-binding / wrapper  your code was using, or will use in future, rather be informed that default values for `ZMQ_LINGER` vary and may cause your code hang-waiting for an infinite amount of time if not all messages were transmitted, yet there is no receiving process to retrieve such hanged-waiting massages from the queue. The best step to avoid this is to always explicitly control the **`ZMQ_LINGER`** settings for all `zmq_socket`-instances and also to explicitly control all the releases of resources by `.unbind()`, `.close()` and `.term()`.

That is a fair and due practice for robust and clean **[distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems)** design

Comment: Thanks @user3666197 for your detailed response, your suggestions helped to solve Packet Loss issue. Heading towards Zen-of-Zero :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would like to ask few questions:
1. How can we identify that zmq_send() / ZMQ_PUB socket enters into Mute state? (zmq_send() function doesn't returns any such indications : http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-send)
2. What analogy helped you to derive those numbers for Publisher side and Subscriber side:
Pub side:
    unsigned long buf_SizeB = 100 * ticks_count; (Why 100?)
Sub side:
    unsigned long hwm_nMSGs =   3 * ticks_count; (Why 3 times?)

Comment: Doubt:
I tried commenting all setsockopt on receiver side and keeping them 0 on sender / publisher side and still I didn't encountered any packet loss, does this means that my sender is now not going into Mute state.

 

Thanks for your highlights on ZMQ_LINGER as well